# How to use ApplicationCommands in a MVVM AvalonDock Program?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I'm working on a program that use AvalonDock to open several documents at the same time. And there is a public ribbon which has some common buttons on the top, like this:
[image]

Now, `Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete` can be used by clicking MenuItems of them in ContextMenu.

However, there are some problems when I want to bind these commands to buttons in the ribbon.

Imitating the example of AvalonDock, my XAML is

```
 <DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:PanesTemplateSelector>
            <local:PanesTemplateSelector.ShapesDocumentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <view:ShapesDocument/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:PanesTemplateSelector.ShapesDocumentTemplate>
        </local:PanesTemplateSelector>
    </DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
 </DockingManager>
```

And my C# is:

```
public ObservableCollection<ShapesDocumentViewModel> Documents { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShapesDocumentViewModel>();
```

So the `ActiveDocument` is a `ViewModel`.

In my `ShapesDocument`, there is a `CanvasEx` with `Cut_Executed`,`Copy_Executed`...

So, how can I bind the CommandTarget? Or there will be some ways to move the `Executed`s into ViewModel?

```
<Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Cut}" CommandTarget="{Binding ???}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily, I use `MenuItem`s to replace the buttons. I set the ApplicationCommands in the Control in `ShapeDocument` UserControl, and binding them to MenuItems without setting the command targets.

I guess that WPF can automaticly search the target of menuitems, but not button. So I can change them to MenuItems, and change the MenuItems' style to imitate buttons.

It's not very elegant but very convinent, with very simple codes.